# Casting a primitive int to a Number

Tags: java, casting, primitive

Let's say that I have the following:

```
int a = 2;
Number b = (Number) a;

System.out.println(b); // Prints 2
```

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/15.doc.html#238146 says that a primitive value may not be cast to a reference type.  Does Java know to create an Integer from the primitive int and then cast to the superclass?  How exactly does Java handle this behind the scenes?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process is called [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). In short, the compiler sees that a wrapper (`Integer`) rather than a primitive (`int`) is needed and automatically adds the conversion. And actually your cast to `Number` is not necessary.